# How to create Build Definitions through VSTS REST API

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, build-definition, azure-devops-rest-api

#### Situation:

I'm currently working on automating CI/CD configurations through bitbucket -> vsts -> azure.

My ideal result is to be able to copy paste (or manually enter) my configuration values into their respective console programs and have the applications configure the whole CI/CD ordeal without having to click through all the web interfaces. It's now possible in Bitbucket and Azure, but creating the VSTS CI/CD configurations through REST API is proving to be difficult.

[Azure resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVPL0.png) and Bitbucket configurations are currently created through a simple .NET console application that talks to the REST APIs. Basically copy paste (or manually enter) all the values ([azure input values](https://pastebin.com/GyZSHA19) / [bitbucket input values](https://pastebin.com/deu85K2L))into the console application and it will configure everything within 5 minutes.

---

#### Problem:

Now I face the harder part of trying to automate build configurations and release configurations in VSTS. Microsoft Docs isn't great on the [documentation of VSTS client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts).

I'm honestly at a loss for how I can [create a build definition](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinition) through the API or Client Library.

- The [BuildHttpClient](https://apisof.net/catalog/M%3AMicrosoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinition,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Int32%7D,System.Object,System.Threading.CancellationToken)) has three methods I can work with:

  ```
  public virtual Task<BuildDefinition> CreateDefinitionAsync(BuildDefinition definition, Guid project, int? definitionToCloneId = null, int? definitionToCloneRevision = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));   
  public virtual Task<BuildDefinition> CreateDefinitionAsync(BuildDefinition definition, int? definitionToCloneId = null, int? definitionToCloneRevision = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));    
  public virtual Task<BuildDefinition> CreateDefinitionAsync(BuildDefinition definition, string project, int? definitionToCloneId = null, int? definitionToCloneRevision = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
  ```
- The [BuildDefinition](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinition) has the following properties.

  ```
  namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi    
  { 
  [DataContract]    
  public class BuildDefinition : BuildDefinitionReference
      {
          public BuildDefinition();

          public List<string> Tags { get; }
          public PropertiesCollection Properties { get; }
          public List<RetentionPolicy> RetentionRules { get; }
          public List<Demand> Demands { get; }
          public IDictionary<string, BuildDefinitionVariable> Variables { get; }
          public List<BuildTrigger> Triggers { get; }
          public ProcessParameters ProcessParameters { get; set; }
          public BuildRepository Repository { get; set; }
          public List<BuildOption> Options { get; }
          public List<BuildDefinitionStep> Steps { get; }
          public bool BadgeEnabled { get; set; }
          public int JobTimeoutInMinutes { get; set; }
          public BuildAuthorizationScope JobAuthorizationScope { get; set; }
          public string DropLocation { get; set; }
          public string Description { get; set; }
          public string Comment { get; set; }
          public string BuildNumberFormat { get; set; }
          public Build LatestBuild { get; }
          public Build LatestCompletedBuild { get; }
      }
   }
  ```

As you can see, the most important properties of a build definition are read-only.

How do I go about creating a build definition through the REST API? Are there better alternatives to VSTS that will allow me to do this?

---

Comment: Have you considered using YAML build? Then your build defintiions are just source-controlled YAML files.

Comment: YAML has the disadvantage that at this current point, Task Groups/templates aren't supported. And that it only supports TFS Git & GitHub, but not bitbucket. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for the REST API to [create a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0) as below:

```
POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0-preview.6
```

application/json example:

```
{
    "process": {
        "phases": [
            {
                "steps": [

                ],
                "name": "Phase 1",
                "refName": "Phase_1",
                "condition": "succeeded()",
                "target": {
                    "executionOptions": {
                        "type": 0
                    },
                    "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
                    "type": 1
                },
                "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
                "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1
            }
        ],
        "type": 1
    },
    "repository": {
        "properties": {
            "cleanOptions": "0",
            "labelSources": "0",
            "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
            "reportBuildStatus": "true",
            "gitLfsSupport": "false",
            "skipSyncSource": "false",
            "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false",
            "fetchDepth": "0"
        },
        "id": "4ba24767-e5a6-4987-80cc-ebaeca01fdbc",
        "type": "TfsGit",
        "name": "product1",
        "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_git/product1",
        "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
        "clean": "false",
        "checkoutSubmodules": false
    },
    "processParameters": {},
    "drafts": [],
    "queue": {
        "id": 324,
        "name": "ownPC",
        "pool": {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "ownPC"
        }
    },
    "name": "definitionCreatedByRESTAPI",
    "type": "build",
    "queueStatus": "enabled"
}
```

To use the REST API in C#, you can convert as below:

```
var personalaccesstoken = "PAT";
var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalaccesstoken}"));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0-preview.6");
requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"process\": {  \"phases\": [{\"steps\": [], \"name\": \"Phase 1\",\"refName\": \"Phase_1\",\"condition\": \"succeeded()\",\"target\": { \"executionOptions\": { \"type\": 0 },\"allowScriptsAuthAccessOption\": false,  \"type\": 1  },  \"jobAuthorizationScope\": \"projectCollection\", \"jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes\": 1 }],\"type\": 1  }, \"repository\": { \"properties\": { \"cleanOptions\": \"0\",\"labelSources\": \"0\",\"labelSourcesFormat\": \"$(build.buildNumber)\", \"reportBuildStatus\": \"true\",\"gitLfsSupport\": \"false\", \"skipSyncSource\": \"false\",\"checkoutNestedSubmodules\": \"false\", \"fetchDepth\": \"0\"},\"id\": \"4ba24767-e5a6-4987-80cc-ebaeca01fdbc\",\"type\": \"TfsGit\",\"name\": \"product1\", \"url\": \"https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_git/product1\", \"defaultBranch\": \"refs/heads/master\",  \"clean\": \"false\",\"checkoutSubmodules\": false },\"processParameters\": {}, \"drafts\": [],\"queue\": { \"id\": 324,  \"name\": \"ownPC\",\"pool\": {\"id\": 23, \"name\": \"ownPC\"}}, \"name\": \"definitionCreatedByRESTAPI\", \"type\": \"build\",\"queueStatus\": \"enabled\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

By referring the blog [Accessing TFS/VSTS 2017 programmatically](https://www.domstamand.com/accessing-tfs-2017-programmatically/) for the C# program.

Comment: Yes! It worked!

It also happens to be that I'm stupid beyond my own expectations. I kept getting 203 unauthorized, because I only entered credentials for READING the response and not credentials WITH the request

Comment: @Mariana, what should be this part of body for Azure DevOps if we want to set default Azure Hosted build agents and queue?   
"queue": {
        "id": 324,
        "name": "ownPC",
        "pool": {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "ownPC"
        }
    },

Comment: @Marina Liu what about the steps info? A build pipeline without steps is pretty much useless. Do you know if there is a way to add them?

Comment: You can use the AzurePipelinePS powershell module to get the release definition Get-APReleaseDefinition as JSON, modify the JSON and post it back using Update-APReleaseDefintion. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS

Comment: I've been running in circles for 4 hours now only to find out that I was using type Git instead of tfsGit