# Azure Devops API Create Build Definition

Tags: azure, tfs, automation, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am trying to find a good example of the json body for Create Build Definition in Azure Devops. Most of the documentation I find has api definitions, but I haven't been able to see an example json body to work from.

Microsoft Documentation:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1`

I have found this article that describes doing something similar to what I hope to accomplish. However, they are trying to duplicate the same build definition across different projects.

Similar Example:

`https://www.nebbiatech.com/2018/11/29/automating-build-pipeline-creation-using-azure-devops-services-rest-api/`

Ultimately, I would like to be able to generate (either create new or clone/modify) as many standard build definitions within a single project as are necessary by my automation. Each one of these build definitions will pull from a different repository within the project and have a different cosmetic name for the pipeline, but will be otherwise identical.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use YAML build. It solves your problem by letting you specify your build definition as a file in source control.

Comment: Hey Daniel! I'm open to that option, but I haven't been able to find much documentation to help get started on that. Do you have any advice on how to begin with that method?

Comment: how about official docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2

Comment: @nuprap As has been pointed out, the official documentation is extensive. Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the usage of YAML build as comment suggested, it will meet your requirements. It letting you define your build in a YAML file that lived with your code. This meant you could **use the same branching and code review practices for your build definitions** as you did for your code.

The best way to get started with YAML pipelines is through the [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2) and [Customize your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops) . After that, to learn how to configure your YAML pipeline the way you need it to work, see conceptual topics such as Build [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

---

As for a sample of application/json body when you use Rest API to create build definition. You could also refer below links:

- [How to create Build Definitions through VSTS REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288144/how-to-create-build-definitions-through-vsts-rest-api)
- [Create VSTS Build Definitions using PowerShell](http://chen.about-powershell.com/2018/07/create-vsts-build-definitions-using-powershell/)

Comment: PatrickLu-MSFT Perfect! This looks like it's exactly what I have been searching for.